# Asp.net RegEx Validation

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need to use an `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` control in my asp.net site and I want to restrict the characters to digits and semi-colon only.

So it needs to be able to take any amount of digits and ;

Valid values:

```
123

123;456

123;456;789;....
```

What is the regex for that?

Comment: If you use `^\d+(?:;\d+)*;?$`? input like ";;5" will be invalid (caught by `^[\d;]+$`).

Comment: same if you try with `^((?:[0-9]+[;])+)$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple regex: `[0-9;]+` or `[\d;]+`

- `\d` match a digit [0-9]
- `;` the literal character ;
- `+` means that it match between one character and unlimited times, as many times as possible,

If you want to guarantee that at least numbers are present in your expression you could do this too:

**@npinti** has a valid point better will be: `^[\d;]+$`

where `^` indicates the begging of your expression and `$` the end of it.

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xG5wR8/1)**

Comment: The above would match `abc9` or `abc;`. Add the `^` and `$` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Always use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` with the RegularExpressionValidator. Although client-side validation works properly with `\d`, server-side validation incorrectly accepts digits from other Unicode scripts as well, like `৯` (Bengali 9).

Comment: Please note that this will validate `;;5`. See my comment above.